# Error in last cell of a table using tabularx

Tags: tables

What's wrong with the last cell of my first table?

This code returns the error \noalign.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|>{\centering}m{1cm}|>{\centering}m{1cm}|>{\centering}m{1cm}|>{\centering}m{1cm}|>{\centering}m{1cm}|>{\centering}m{1cm}|}
        \hline
                     & \multicolumn{6}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{Bla} \\ \cline{2-7}
                     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &     6     \\ \hline
         Activity 1  & x &   &   &   &   &           \\ \hline
         Activity 2  &   & x &   &   &   &           \\ \hline
         Activity 3  &   &   & x & x & x &           \\ \hline
         Activity 4  &   &   &   &   & x &     x     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

This one looks good, but the last column is irregular:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}

    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|>{\centering}m{1cm}|>{\centering}m{1cm}|>{\centering}m{1cm}|>{\centering}m{1cm}|>{\centering}m{1cm}|c|}
        \hline
                    & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Bla} \\ \cline{2-7}
                    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &     6     \\ \hline
        Activity 1  & x &   &   &   &   &           \\ \hline
        Activity 2  &   & x &   &   &   &           \\ \hline
        Activity 3  &   &   & x & x & x &           \\ \hline
        Activity 4  &   &   &   &   & x &     x     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Second table:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I get an error when I try to compile your code. Don't you?

Comment: Yeah, but if you compile a normal table and compile the code after it, it will show you the table of the image.  At least for me. Thanks for answering.

Comment: The point is that you are posting the image and not the error. You should be asking about the error, since that is almost certainly why the image isn't the one you want. As I say, if you ignore errors, you should expect weird output. You should never ignore compilation errors. This one told you what was wrong and why your image looked the way it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an error and ignore it, you can't expect the output to be correct, even if you do get a document as a result. The error message in this case reports a 'misplaced \noalign' which usually means you've tried to insert more columns than you specified.

The reason for this is that you cannot use `\\` to end the line as you've configured your tabular. Either use `\tabularnewline` or add `\arraybackslash` to the relevant columns, as you did for the `C` specification in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|}
        \hline
                     & \multicolumn{6}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{Bla} \\ \cline{2-7}
                     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &     6     \\ \hline
         Activity 1  & x &   &   &   &   &           \\ \hline
         Activity 2  &   & x &   &   &   &           \\ \hline
         Activity 3  &   &   & x & x & x &           \\ \hline
         Activity 4  &   &   &   &   & x &     x     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Cronograma}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: fixed alignments]

You need the `\arraybackslash` in the column specification for `m` for just the same reason you need it in defining `C`, only more so, because you are actually trying to end the tabular row in one of the `m` columns.

Comment: It worked. Maybe my answer wasn't well explained, sorry. But how to center the "Bla"? Thanks

Comment: @EijiWatanabe Use `\multicolumn{6}{c}` ?